# XNA/MonoGame Mouse Over Cards

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

[image]

Blue overlaps Green which overlaps Red.

Each card can be selected by passing the mouse over it. But the thing my hitboxes don't have a depth notion (z-axis), it's a 2D game.

So lets say that i want to select the **Green** Card when i put my mouse over it the **Green and the Red are selected** because the cursor is in the Green HitBox but also in the Red HitBox.

So my question is how should i manage this: When i have overlapping hitboxes, how to check only the area that are not covered ?

Note : I use the Rectangle Intersect and Contains functions.

Comment: my approach will be to recalculate hitbox for each card to size of only visible part of card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But the thing my hitboxes don't have a depth notion (z-axis), it's a 2D game....So my question is how should i manage this

Just because it's a 2D game (and by that I mean the camera is projecting some world from *x*D to 2D) **doesn't mean your scene has to be in 2D**.  Because your cards can overlap one another **your scene has depth** and so it is 3D.

Once you realise this, hit detection of objects in your 3D scene are trivial.

i.e.

1. shoot a ray from the mouse, inverse projected into the scene
2. test to see which objects it hits
3. take the first object closest to the origin

[image]

Comment: Now that i see your solution, i feel completely dumb to not have thought of it... :p Thank you for your solution.